# Zend\Crypt\Password\BCrypt verify method

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bcrypt, password-encryption

I am using [`Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt/blob/master/src/Password/Bcrypt.php) for storing passwords encrypted in the database. But now I looked a bit closer and I don't seem to understand [the verify method of this class](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt/blob/master/src/Password/Bcrypt.php#L102):

```
/**
 * Verify if a password is correct against a hash value
 *
 * @param  string $password
 * @param  string $hash
 * @throws Exception\RuntimeException when the hash is unable to be processed
 * @return bool
 */
public function verify($password, $hash)
{
    $result = crypt($password, $hash);
    return Utils::compareStrings($hash, $result);
}
```

Functionality according to the comment *"Verify if a password is correct against a hash value"*

But when I check [the php crypt function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) it is calling the second argument is an optional `$salt` and not a `$hash` string to verify.

How I am reading this: it first uses the passed `$hash` as salt to encrypt the `$password` that we want to check and then it compares the same `$hash` it used as salt with the encrypted `$result` !?

So what am I missing here? Either the php-doc is not correct or I am not understanding what is happening or I missed something in the documents.

Comment: This is a bit odd seeing how Bcrypt shouldn't be verified by comparing 2 strings but by using password_verify(). I would love a explanation for this aswell

Comment: @Crecket Zend\Crypt\Password\Bcrypt was created before the password_* function was added to PHP core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bcrypt hash has well documented structure, for example this hash:

```
$2y$10$aPk2mEEIkGonq6/JGr0OKOhYOdgomu61ARBjDLgb0UmHM4L8f7Hxe
```

String `$2y$` is prefix, `10` is cost, `aPk2mEEIkGonq6/JGr0OKO` is salt (128-bit, base64 encoded 22 characters) and `hYOdgomu61ARBjDLgb0UmHM4L8f7Hxe` is resulting hash.

[`crypt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function recognizes this format and use appropriate part of it as a salt, so there is no problem to pass whole hash as second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently it is not a problem, but very confusing and I guess not only to me. I think they should update the documentation and explain that the second argument can be either the salt or a hash.