# ZfzUser Authentication Always fails

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have implemented ZfcUser in my application. The problem is that the authentication always fails even if the password is correct.

I have digged into the problem. What I have noticed is that, the application retrieves password hash from the password and pass it to the Bcrypt verify method.

Here is the code from Zend

```
if (!$bcrypt->verify($credential, $userObject->getPassword())) {
    // Password does not match
    $e->setCode(AuthenticationResult::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID)
      ->setMessages(array('Supplied credential is invalid.'));
    $this->setSatisfied(false);
    return false;
}
```

Now the bcrypt verify method works as follows.

```
public function verify($password, $hash)
{
    $result = crypt($password, $hash);
    return Utils::compareStrings($hash, $result);
}
```

my password is `'admin123'`, the generated hash saved for it in database is `"$2y$14$9QsDD3.T3xwCnZsMsiBft.fwLewL.0L5pyViAJY0EbNz0ECIGDi5u"`

but I see that it will never match, because the verify method uses the Hash value as salt. I am doing something wrong, or is there some bug in the framework/?

the code used to setup the password in my User Entity is

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $bcrypt = new Bcrypt();
    $bcrypt->setCost(14);
    $this->password = $bcrypt->create($password);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend\Crypt\Password\BCrypt verify method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717509/zend-crypt-password-bcrypt-verify-method)

Answer (score 0):

I asked exactly [the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717509/zend-crypt-password-bcrypt-verify-method).

It turns out that crypt can use the hash. It will break it down in usable pieces and then it will use appropriate part of it as a salt, so there is no problem to pass whole hash as second parameter.

Did you actually try? Could it be that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe then I am storing the password in wrong way in the database because the result hash is different from the password has in db. I have included the code in original post for password generation to save in database. Kindly have a look at it that it is correct.

Comment: @backTangent After you created the password immediately try: `$bcrypt->verify($password, $this->password);`